# Which clustering algorithm to use for categorical features

Tags: r

Which clustering algorithm I should be using for the below type of dataset.
Say I have dataset with two variables (one is Age and another is say var). 
I converted them to the binary format as shown below. Kindly help me with the following questions

1.Should I use k-means directly on the data ?

2.Can I use hierarchical clustering ? if so which distance measuring algorithm

3.Or is there any better approach for this feature transformation and algorithm

```
Age var
24  x1
54  x2
18  x1
45  x3
30  x2
```

I converted the categorical feature to this way

```
Age var.x1 var.x2 var.x3
24  1       0      0
54  0       1      0
18  1       0      0
45  0       0      1
30  0       1      0
```

Answer (score 1):

K-means assumes *continuous* variables. So no, do not use k-means.

Hierarchical clustering is fine. Choose *any* of the distance metrics. Whatever works for your data, there is not one "best" solution.